Why CPUMiner does not mine in spite of showing good hash rate?
I tried cpuminer to mine some nominal crypto. But, even after 12+hours , not even one share has been obtained. What is the problem in my command. Like, I used the command
./cpuminer -a scrypt -o stratum+tcp://scrypt.mine.zergpool.com:6533 -u <wallet> -p c=<Payoutcurrency>
and the terminal then shows
 New Block 3457268, Tx 0, Netdiff 0.14933, Job 3a                Diff: Net 0.14933, Stratum 256, Target 0.0039062 TTF @ 24.36 kh/s: Block 7h18m, Share 11m28s Net hash rate (est) 53.45 Mh/s
But, even after a long time, no acceptance of jobs or submissions take place, and i do not get any crypto.
As regards the low hash rate, I was able to mine a few satoshis using cheaper algorithms like ghostrider and randomx on xmrig on even less hash rates. But, with cpuminer i do not get even a single satoshi. How to rectify this? Or, can we run xmrig using scrypt or sha512256d algorithms on some pool?
Any hints?

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael yes. though the question is related to more general cryptocurrency, but bitcoin mining is also implied.

Does "In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?" answer your question?

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael i actually made a few satoshis using my CPU in aday. Well, the rate is like 40 Sat/day, very less, but I got an idea how mining works. Maybe using USB based ASIC, I could scale it to 2000 sat/day

@Murch No, that question describes the practical cons of cpu mining, I wanted to know how it actually is done, and how I could scale it. In this case, I reached a workable solution for my cpu using cpuminer / xmrig. Now, I should be able to scale it to large shares using multiple CPUs/usb based asic stick

I just tried with the algorithms yespower and yescrypt and they worked, although the speed in yespower is very less. By the way, the reason I guess that the scrypt algorithm did not work was, because in the pool, they were designated for either GPU/ASIC/FPGA, which I did not use.
